# How to hide password in chrome react developer tool?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome

[React react developer tool inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veZMT.png)

> How to hide/prevent password value to appear in inspector as a state
>   in reactjs when handling form submit in case of using chrome react
>   developer tool?

Comment: I personally have no clue what you are asking. You can not hide values from people....

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, could you provide some code of your specific problem. That prove how far did you try and it will help other members to understand your problem better, at the time, you will give them a context of your issue. Please, check these links: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to hide any information that is saved in a variable or in the state of your app from being displayed in react-dev-tools.

Thats exactly why the react-dev-tools extension for chrome is so useful. 
You can see what values you have and how they might/might not change.